# How do I fix the message "Error from bundle install --without production"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, rubygems

When I try to run the

```
 bundle install --without production
```

command on cloudi9, I get an error message like this:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Any ideas about why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: are you using any json data in your app?

Comment: add your gemfile code.

Comment: I got it to work after tinkering with it, and some researching

Answer (score 0):

if you run which bundler and the return value is not rbenv something something try this:

```
gem install bundler && rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of newer versions of ruby solved the problem for me.

```
1)  sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

2)  gem install bundler
```

Comment: Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.5' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Thats what I get when I run  bundle install --without production